# Segmentation fault in c++ recursive function

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, c++17

```
//void squarewall function below is showing error

void squareWall(int s) {
      static int count=0;
      if(count == s)
         return ;

      string t;
      for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
          t = t + "* ";
      }
      cout<<t<<"\n";
      count++;
      return squareWall(s);

}
```

I have written function to print square pattern of * in c++ using single loop and recursive call . It is giving correct output for custom cases but showing segmentation fault at the time of submission. Can someone explain what's the case here.

Comment: Curiously, this is tail recursive, which means that, at least for optimized builds, it is't actually "recursive" under the covers.

Comment: Are you calling `squareWall` twice with different values?

Comment: Static variables and recursion is an unpleasant combination. This function can only be called meaningfully once, and for instance `squareWall(2);squareWall(1);` will never terminate.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not tail recursive since the string needs to be destroyed after the recursion returns.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Theoretically, you're right. But in practice, `t` is local, and no reference to it ever exits the function, so a compiler could destroy `t` *before* calling, and still be conforming.

Comment: Just don't call this with a lower number than you've ever called it with before.  Your counter only goes forward.  `squareWall(2); squareWall(1);` will cause the crash because the counter `count` doesn't reset between calls because it's static (is only initialized on the first call).

Comment: Instead of the static, you can pass the number of lines to the function as an argument. You can then decrement it in the recursive call.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am calling it only once in program to print square pattern of "*".

Comment: Check what values are being passed in. So far the only values that cause your code to run forever are negative numbers. I ran the code with all the values up to `10000` and it worked fine. `-1`, instant stack overflow.

Comment: @SURAJMAHAKAL please provide the **complete** reproducible example with all the pieces included such as `#include <string>` `#include <iostream>`, `using namespace std;` and a `main` function that calls `squareWall` and _make sure it reproduces the crash_.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I checked, GCC 12.2 and clang with `-fwhole-program -O3` can't transform this to be tail recursive :( https://godbolt.org/z/Mnfo1Yfj4

Comment: @MooingDuck So your practice worked in theory but not in practice... ;-)

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite code avoiding the `static` variable or, at least, rewrite `if(count == s) return ;` as `if(count == s) { count = 0; return; }`

Comment: MSVC also can't pull off the optimization :( https://godbolt.org/z/eKbz559a1
I wonder if it's some quirk where the memory release counts as "a side effect" that can't be rearranged. If so, they need to fix that.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes, It works, before i got inverted triangle pattern as the parameter of function is directly used in for loop for condition checking. Instead of assigning it to other static variable;

Comment: @Wyck,  Your suggestions worked on problem with changes stated by max66. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your variable `count` is static, it gets declared once, after which it doesn't get assigned zero. That's why this function doesn't go into infinite recursion, but it is also why when you call your function a second time, *it doesn't initialize the counter*.

So, if you do something like this

```cpp
squareWall(size);
squareWall(size);
```

the first call succeeds, but the second time, since `count` is still equal to `size`, your function immediately returns.

However, in this example

```cpp
squareWall(size);
squareWall(size - 1);
```

the first call still succeeds, but the second call will **not** return to the guard clause, since `count == size`, `s == size - 1`. After that, your function will never return, so it ends up in an infinite recursion, which at some point causes the SEGFAULT.

Using static variables in recursive functions is generally not a good practice that tends to cause situations like this. A solution would be to declare `count` as an argument with a default value:

```cpp
void squareWall(int s, int count = 0)
{
  if (count == s)
    return;

  string t;
  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
  {
    t = t + "* ";
  }
  
  cout << t << "\n";
  return squareWall(s, count + 1);
}
```